# Striping slashes except if a user enters file directory path in string like C:\test\

Tags: php, stripslashes

Is there a way to use `stripslashes()` without removing slashes if the string contains a file directory path?

```
$string = "C:\test\";
echo stripslashes($string);
```

Comment: something like `if(!preg_match('/[a-z]:/i'),$string) {stripslashes(string)}` should work...

Comment: How would you know when it's not a directory path? Paths in windows start with `[a-z]:`, by on both Mac and Linux a path can be pretty much anything starting with `/`